# Image downloaded from REST API is corrupted in react js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

I am using react js on front end and spring boot for backend API's.
Https Entity is returned from API controller.
It is viewable on Postman but when I download it on browser in react app, it says image can't be opened because it may be damaged.

**REST Controller**

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/receipt")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public HttpEntity<byte[]> generateTransactionReceipt(
            @RequestBody DirectCardDebitTransactionRecordDTO directCardDebitTransactionRecord) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        byte[] fileBytes = disputeReceiptService.printReceiptForDispute("Amount",
                directCardDebitTransactionRecord);

        HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType("image/jpeg");
        header.setContentType(mediaType);
        header.set("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=receipt" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toInstant().toString()
                        + ".jpg");
        header.setContentLength(fileBytes.length);

        return new HttpEntity<>(fileBytes, header);
    }
```

**React App**

```
printReceipt = () => {
            const {Host} = this.state.Host;
            const {record} = this.state;
            api.send({
                        url: `${Host}/api/v1/receipt`,
                        method: 'post',
                        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                        headers: {
                            Accept: 'application/json',
                          },
                        data: {record},
                        skipAuthHeader: false,
                    }).then((response) => {
                                  if (response.status === 200) {
                                  console.log('Response')
                                  console.log(response);
                                      const data = response.data
                                      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data.json]));
                                      const link = document.createElement('a');
                                      link.href = url;
                                      link.setAttribute('download', 'receipt.jpeg');
                                      document.body.appendChild(link);
                                      link.click();
                                  } else {
                                      console.error(response);
                                      notification.open({
                                          type: 'error',
                                          message: 'Error occurred in fetching the receipt',
                                          duration: 3,
                                      });
                                  }
                              })
                              .catch((error) => {
                                  console.log(error)
                              });
        };
```

**Postman**

```
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 1ed415b2-38f3-4dcd-889c-00776a8f528a
Host: localhost:9504
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 7793
Request Body
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with,x-auth-username,x-auth-password,x-auth-token,origin,accept,content-type,access-control-request-method,access-control-request-headers,authorization,Cache-Control
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 669437
Date: Mon, 19 Feb 2024 06:02:48 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

What can done to properly download the image in the browser.

Comment: You're passing header type 'application/json'' from Front end which is wrong in case of image, you have to send header 'image/jpeg' in case of images. Other than this, I think you're creating blob from ''response.data.json' instead of this, you should directly create a blob from response.data only.